# Is there a PyTorch lightning equivalent for Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I saw PyTorch Lightning advertised as PyTorch but for people who don't want to worry so much about the underlying methodology. This narrative is on the PyTorch lightning website but also [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/use-pytorch-lightning-to-decouple-science-science-code-from-engineering-code-1e6f36cf6a1a) for example.

For hardware reasons, does something similar exist for TensorFlow? I have a code example for [neural nets here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/MilesCranmer/PySR/blob/master/examples/pysr_demo.ipynb#scrollTo=8ZqGupq_uSgp) written in PyTorch and PyTorch Lightning but am not sure how to rewrite it in TensorFlow.

Comment: Probably the best association would be Keras (formerly separate from but now for some time integrated in TF - you can you Keras as a high level API).

Comment: @TimbusCalin thank you! It did indeed simplify things. If you want to write this up as an answer, I shall happily accept it.

Comment: I will do that now, thank you - I also added additional explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE:

You should probably opt for `keras-cv` or `keras-nlp` now as they integrate computer vision and nlp applications better, `tensorflow_addons` is soon going to be deprecated.

Probably the best association would be Keras (formerly separate from but now for some time integrated in TF - you can you Keras as a high level API).

Note that you can also use `tensorflow_addons` (I personally enjoy working with it) package and other libraries&wrappers that come into the aid of TensorFlow, because since Keras is integrated into TF, you will be also very likely to use them on your Keras code.